# iOS Network Reachability always return NotReach when the iOS device connect to VPN

Tags: ios, vpn, reachability

i use AFNewWorkReachability check the network status，but the reachability always false when the device connecting the vpn network.why,and how fix? ths

Answer (score 0):

The `Reachability` only tells you the status of local connection. The solution is to use `RealReachability`.

https://github.com/dustturtle/RealReachability

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should test your VPN.
I use the VPN in iphoneX, ios11 and use the AFNetworking, it work correctly.